# Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument with UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

After upgrading to Xcode7.2, I have this warning:

```
Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
```

I only know how to satisfy non-null requirement to avoid this warning for string by using @"" instead of nil. **However I don't know how to do so in the case of UIImageView** and here below is my code:

```
if (imageFile)
        {
            UIImageView *imageLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [imageLabel setTag:CellImageLabelTag];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageLabel];

        } else {
            UIImageView *imageLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [imageLabel setTag:CellImageLabelTag];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:nil]; //warning here
        }
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot add nil as subview. What do you relally want to achieve? Do you want to remove all subviews?

Comment: There is no point to calling `addSubview:` with a `nil` argument. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Or do you want to add the `imageLabel`? Then it should be `[cell.contentView addSubview:imageLabel]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add the image view to the cell? If so you would need to do the following:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageLabel];
```

The compiler is showing that warning because the method `addSubview` takes a `nonnull UIView *` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *imageLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageLabel setTag:CellImageLabelTag];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageLabel ]; //No warning here anymore :-)
```